# Can I input Chinese in my xterm?

Tags: ubuntu, unicode, xterm

I have Chinese input working. I have xterm working. I have utf-8 working in my xterm. For example, I can see the lightning bolt unicode character. But when I input Chinese characters, I get those blocks. Whats up with that?

Here is what I'm doing in my .Xresources:

```
xterm*faceName: Monospace:9
xterm*boldFont: Monospace:9
xterm*faceNameDoublesize: Monospace:9
```

Also, I'm using iBus to input Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

Oh.  I figured it out.

```
xterm*faceNameDoublesize:WenQuanYi Micro Hei:antialias=true:pixelsize=20
```

Monospace doesn't have chinese characters.  (Duh. :)